# Output phase voltage of wye-connected synchronous generator

Tags: ac, generator, three-phase, synchronous

The question:

[image]

The answer:

[image]

However, theta is the angle difference between the terminal phase voltage and the line current as shown in Figure 20 below

[image]

So, I think the answer would be

512/*12 - 47/*-34.9 * (0.6+1.3j) = 447.8/_11.6 V

Am I right?

Comment: I think you are wrong. It seems like the statement of the problem gives the both the generated  voltage phase angle and load phase angle with respect to an arbitrary zero reference angle. The solution is then worked out in terms of that reference. I think that is what needs to be done. Once the angle between the generated voltage and the terminal voltage is known, you can rotate everything to make the terminal voltage angle zero and relate the current to that. I don't think it makes sense to relate the current angle to the terminal voltage angle before the terminal voltage is known.